# Definition of the smooth local convergence of a sequence of hypersurfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I'm reading a lecture note on mean curvature flows (by C. Mantegazza) and studying about analysis of type-I singularities.

Let $M$ be a smooth closed $n$-dimensional manifold and $\varphi:M\times[a,\infty)\stackrel{C^\infty}\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a mapping such that for each $s\in[a,\infty)$ the map $\varphi_s:=\varphi(\underline\ ,s):M\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is an immersion.

Then what does the statement "a sequence of hypersurfaces $\left(\varphi_{s_i}\right)_i$ locally smoothly converges (up to reparametrization) to some limit hypersurface $M_\infty$" mean?

Reading the following context in my textbook, the above statement seems to be strictly rougher than that "the sequence of maps $(\varphi_{s_i})$ converges to an immersion $\varphi_\infty$ in $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$". It seems that $M_\infty$ can be unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ while $M$ is assumed to be closed.

The figure below is what I am reading in the textbook. Here we set $\tilde\varphi$ to be the rescaling of a smooth solution of the mean curvature flow $\dfrac{\partial \varphi_t}{\partial t}=\Delta^t\varphi_t$ which develops a type I singularities at t=T.

[image: a]

I am glad if you show me an example of nontrivial convergence of hypersurfaces. Here the term "trivial" means the convergence of the immersions in $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quiet unclear and (interestingly) has been used (without proof) as early as the work in Huisken' 1990 paper when he defined type I singularity. The point is that when you have a type I singularity, the second fundamental form satisfies a bound

$$\max _{\varphi_t(\cdot)} |A|^2 \le \frac{C_0}{T-t}$$

for some fixed constant $C_0$. Then one can define the rescaling (I am following the book by XP Zhu, so the normalizing constant might be different)

$$\tilde \varphi (x, \tau) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(T-t)}} (\varphi_t(x) -P), \ \ \tau = -\frac 12 \log\left( \frac{T-t}{t}\right)$$

This scaling factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(T-t)}}$ has the advantage that 
$$\sup_\tau |\tilde A|^2 \le C$$

for all $\tau$, where $\tilde A$ is the second fundamental form of $\tilde \varphi$. Now using the (parabolic) equation for $|\tilde A|^2$, one can show that there are unform bound on all higher derivatives:

$$\sup_\tau |\tilde\nabla^m \tilde A|^2 \le C(m),\ \ \ \forall m.$$

And this condition (together with the fact that $\tilde\varphi_\tau$ do not excape to infinity) will forces that whenever you pick $\tau_i\to \infty$, there is a subsequence so that $\tilde \varphi_{\tau_i}$ converges locally smoothly to a hypersurfaces $\phi_\infty : M_\infty \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$.

You are right that $M_\infty$ will not be the topologically the same as $M$ in general. For example, you can start with the standard torus in $\mathbb R^3$ which is a surface of revolution. Then when you apply the MCF, when the torus will shrinks to a $\mathbb S^1$. Now if you choose any points $P$ in this $\mathbb S^1$ and apply the blow up at $P$, your get actually a cylinder $M_\infty$, which is not the torus.

Now go back to the claimed convergence. One can actually find a proof in the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4562.pdf) by Patrick Breuning (Theorem 1.3) in 2012. There are also some previous works on hypersurfaces, you may find that in the reference. So you are right that it is not a convergence as a mapping $\varphi_i \to \varphi_\infty$, but it is still quite strong as a convergence (locally smoothly)